# Supress/remove repeated values in Jdeveloper/ADF Table column

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I need to supress the repeated values in a table so it will look like:

```
x y z
- - u
- b z
- - u
y y z
- - u
```

instead:

```
x y z
x y u
x b z
x b u
y y z
y y u
```

In Oracle OBI I can do that editing column properties of a table:

[image]

But I can't find this option in column/table properties from Jdeveloper, there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a table.
You can use a pivot table to do this.
Or you can use an af:iterator to create this type of UI.